# Why are my windows scrolling together?

Tags: gvim, scrolling, plugin-fugitive

I have two windows open on the same buffer and I want to edit two parts of the same file at the same time.  I can't because the windows are scrolling together.  I have `noscrollbind` set so I am confused by this.  What else could be causing this?

If I start a new session then the problem goes away.  I'd prefer not to have to close my session because I have memorized all the buffer numbers.

Comment: check `:windo :set cursorbind? scrollbind?`

Comment: `cursorbind` and `scrollbind` are both off.  `:windo` is a command that, to my knowledge, I am not using.

Comment: I meant to type that command litteraly, e.g. including the :windo so you can see, if it is set in any window.

Comment: Cool.  It turns out that `cursorbind` *was* set.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/why-are-my-windows-scrolling-together#comment8656_5601) in the comments, this was caused by the `'cursorbind'` setting.

`:help 'cursorbind'`:

> When this option is set, as the cursor in the current window moves other cursorbound windows (windows that also have this option set) move their cursors to the corresponding line and column.  This option is useful for viewing the differences between two versions of a file (see 'diff'); in diff mode, inserted and deleted lines (though not characters within a line) are taken into account.